# Generate function from no initilized object or get keys from type and create functions by key

Tags: typescript

```
const myFunctions = {
  data1 : <number | undefined>undefined,
  data2 : <string[] | undefined>undefined,
  data3 : <string | undefined>undefined,
  data4 : <undefined | undefined>undefined,
}

type TFunctions<Obj> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: (
    value: NonNullable<Obj[Prop]>
  ) => void
}
const functionGenerator = <T>(fObj:T):TFunctions<T> => {
  const funObj:any = {}
  for(const key in fObj){
    funObj[key] = (payload : any) :void => { console.log(payload)}
  }
  return funObj;
}
const f = functionGenerator(myFunctions)
f.data1(1) //good
f.data2(['a','b']) //good
f.data3('test') //good
f.data4() // error try run empty function
```

is there some option make this code cleaner remove all undefined
and make data4 available run as function that receive nothing

i try find how get keys from type and create function on this but its look impassible as type is TypeScript declaration and no Variable

[image]

Webstorm its give me error on f.data4() as its 'Expected 1 arguments, but got 0'

Comment: Do you want to allow calling without argument or not? What are constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example:

```js
interface Data {
    data1: number,
    data2: string[]
    data3: string
    data4: undefined
}

type MakeUndefined<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] | undefined
}

const myFunctions: MakeUndefined<Data> = {
    data1: undefined,
    data2: undefined,
    data3: undefined,
    data4: undefined,
}

type TFunctions<Obj> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]:
    NonNullable<Obj[Prop]> extends undefined // if data4 is undefined - no arguments
    ? () => void
    : (value: NonNullable<Obj[Prop]>) => void
}
const functionGenerator = <T,>(fObj: T): TFunctions<T> =>
    (Object.keys(fObj) as Array<keyof T>)
        .reduce((acc, elem) => ({
            ...acc,
            [elem]: (payload: any): void => { }
        }), {} as TFunctions<T>
        )

const f = functionGenerator(myFunctions)

f.data1(1) //good
f.data2(['a', 'b']) //good
f.data3('test') //good
f.data4() // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUMg5AEwzgEYAuZEAVwFsAjaAGn0JMwCYqBnMKUAHMA2gF02BDnADMvfkInFSAFio0QRCDFAQiuAL65cYAJ4AHFAFk4AawgBVDVp1EAPABUAfMgC8ORcIAClAA9mbIoMh2JiEwyO6iVO5BoWaiyAA+yOqa2iC6BkYIISB8yHQmAGLqCGDAJTxU1naOuS6u6JjefniESpiU2U55uqx9UtxDbflEY+ykslPOM3OSKmrDLqyGxuYo7tUgtfWlrgDyDABW3f59KWERIFEQMXEXl4mKAHIlXzQANv84Ax-hBzld7mlvBAAB6QDQ8JYjIjIAD0qIicSkygiiJyy10yAAtNQQsg4FBBPQIOAeIoAPzIAAUAEpfN4AG4hYB6PpUJkcuD-GgQKg-EB-QHA0Hgy6Q0SeNk+TncvSGYqlMDIGA1OolADiNOgGBCUF8yA8zE8TJg7ySLKSh2ODQ83U8iiZ7wgtQAdNEeDb3my4IiAIJQKBwEyuaKxeKKxR9H1QXQ0JBMpmIBDMZAQUF0JXeJm9Pqlgg+itZ1ZlwjCPMQOiJZlmKP-EJwIhUOAgEwO5BcnnsnDIQw1kcsnPYfTkxEHXUnHiuxOEFlFBpauJ+HVHPUgQ35SNgU1MipO3c8Ve4GA+qRkJlkNnowQhEJ6a8TJnCADkcC-Oa-DBfqIj6os+r5XjeCxMl+kB8F+IFgW+kGYMorJohiIQ2LgQA)

I mad small update in `TFunctions` since all keys should exists

Comment: f.data4() Cannot be run without arguments :/

if only there was a way minimize to 1 object as the functionGenerator will be reused in many places on ES6 its passible write
`
const myFunctions = {
    data1,
    data2,
    data3,
    data4,
}
`
loop on all keys create functions but then there is no auto complete of types

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Pls provide an example. `Cannot be run without arguments` - is it good or bad?

Comment: maybe f.data4() error is only on WebStorm
 Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

Comment: @Vasa made an update

Comment: i change the question and post there image of f.data4() error

Comment: @Vasa made an update

Comment: do you think is there some problem use this code
https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys
for make auto transform of interface Data to const myFunctions?

Comment: Personally I don't think it is a good idea to mix type scope and runtime values. These two worlds should be separated forever :D

Comment: i have other structure of data for 'const myFunctions' that i think can solve the problem but actually its look crazy think of implementationof this on typescript :/ , open new case on it or publish it here?

Comment: @Vasa if you have other question please publish it as a separate. If this question is resolved you can accept it

Comment: i have second variant of functionGeneretor can you please help solve the .type problem 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69981275/function-generator-from-object-that-contain-functions-function-name-is-by-key