# Function Generator from object that contain functions , function name is by key value is the function body

Tags: typescript, type-inference, typescript-generics, type-constraints

My code:

```js
import {
  createAction
} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const myFunctions = {
  f1: (payload: number) => ({
    payload,
  }),
  f2: (payload: string) => ({
    payload,
  }),
  f3: () => ({}),
}

type TFunctions<Obj> = {
  [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop]
}
const functionGenerator = <_, T>(prefix: string, fObj: T): TFunctions<T> => {
  const returnFunctions: any = {}
  Object.keys(fObj).map(key => {
    returnFunctions[key] = createAction(`${prefix}/${key}`, fObj[key]) // error
  })
  return returnFunctions;
}

export const myFunction = functionGenerator(PREFIX, myFunctions)
myFunction.f1(123)
sagaActions.f1.type // type is string of `${prefix}/${key}`
myFunction.f2('text')
sagaActions.f2.type // type is string of `${prefix}/${key}`
myFunction.f3()

export const sagaActions = functionGenerator(ADMIN, myFunctions)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

technically this code working but i can't find right typescript for remove this errors.
i beginner in typescript

**Errors :**

**1:** createAction secound parameter Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.

**2:** Array.prototype.map() expects a return value from arrow function.(array-callback-return)

**3 :** Property 'type' does not exist on type '(payload: number) => { payload: number; }'.

from 1 2 i can ignore i will try find some solutions or set in file ignore for all errors but 3 its critical as it used on other files and i can't understand how in [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] i add the type value to be string

**4 :** ReturnType<typeof myFunction.?> automatic detection does not work

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQQWTYCAOwBo48DiBhdLaAdWBgAsAFdMDdAE1YwE8ANhAzc4AXzgAzKBBBwA5AAEeAVwAeAKwDOAehgQIggNZMFAWABQV5MW3wQ-AGKqi+QkW1wAvIitxpAEYALjgACk4hEW5QolUQACM0KABKHwA+cIR-ALhI4VESHPEUossAqQAmUIiBApi4eyhgIgBzNO9MsOzy3PzosoCSwekAZhqOroRhq3ErKxh+MDQ4ACU0blVkZIAeHIB5BM04NHVsIm4vddsobh2mltayMIA6N65W7VCMIn4AbQAupNEHk6tFvr8JOkRuw0FJgOoTmc0BcvA82jlMr4erk4H92BAwHAWnBjGh+BApHBDpoAcEcgEKB4aJgDFBGCxYZweHwoqI9r1cXwoBgQGhsFBtDsafjZGAAdCGbl1jBVFAiAAVJZoaVHWWEhV-BT9UQKAEjXEAAwAJAhYfD1OJdLaCUSAGSNGDNNriS1K9LFeaWWyeeBSVzuYgAcRRyToUB8cAFAXtCKR50unu9TxyGvTKMz12gd3RT3CbxeHy+cB+-yBGRrvwDlnSEXQDtCqfUZCkNNCGsmOTCNLQ+BeZP42jCvaOaQwXhwUBF-B2E8pcA16RSLzU2zCYQwyGQZDQgjQIGB3SVFcPx6Vf1P57pKFo2CZxDCNoQYHbCKdtsfEBfR7GVAKBYpSkQSR5zWDYtl2DUyC7Lcg1OSBYBQOwHGcCNKCIRNwzcPCYyIOM2TCBQAGIpEMBQyEcFwiI8bQUisBjcI8F4pECMJAkqUZt0WZY4F0XQ4AAImowxdG48S2JwpjiC4yoKOwM4FEE7URN0SSaIgGTKjkyx2MUoguNGMJNOE0SJKk-SpFGIyFi0jUnECRMVTVTVtR2IS0HXEzIzM5s-I3JxKkTPyAoUoLlKsIA)

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the text of the errors you are asking about, not just pictures of text.

Comment: sorry you right next time i will explicit specific problem of the code
I thought because there is no tool here that will show what the problem is a picture will show it

Comment: As for the question, you're using `map` for side effects; just use the result. `return Object.keys(fObj)).map(key => createAction(`${prefix}/${key}`,fObj[key]));` or, if you really want it to be an object, use `fromEntries`: `return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys(fObj).map(key => [key, createAction(`${prefix}/${key}`,fObj[key])]))`  That would fix error 2. You don't show `createAction` and the other errors depend on that function, so can't help there.

Comment: import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
createAction this reduxjs function

Answer (score 2):

I assume `sagaActions` is not a part of this question, hence I will ignore them.

First of all, from my experience, if you  want to mutate accumulator object inside `map` loop it is better to use `[].reduce` instead.

If you want to obtain return type of `createAction` function - you should refer to [ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/2ff1fa4364ce0dfa82dbbd3187aa0c63e57d5582/packages/toolkit/src/createAction.ts#L102) type

If you want to infer literal type of `prefix` argument, you should create extra generic for this purpose.
Consider this very simple example: `const foo=<Prefix>(prefix:Prefix)=>null`.
If you are interested in inference on function arguments you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments).

Full code:

```js
import { createAction, ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const myFunctions = {
  f1: (payload: number) => ({
    payload,
  }),
  f2: (payload: string) => ({
    payload,
  }),
  f3: () => ({}),
}

type Reducer<
  Obj extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => { payload: any }>,
  Prefix extends string
  > = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]:
    ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload<
      Parameters<Obj[Prop]>,
      ReturnType<Obj[Prop]>['payload'],
      `${Prefix}/${Prop & string}`
    >
  }

const functionGenerator = <
  Prefix extends string,
  T extends Record<string, (...args: any[]) => any>
>(prefix: Prefix, fObj: T) =>
  (Object.keys(fObj) as Array<keyof T>).reduce((acc, elem) => ({
    ...acc,
    [elem]: createAction(`${prefix}/${elem}`, fObj[elem])
  }), {} as Reducer<T, Prefix>)

export const myFunction = functionGenerator('#foo', myFunctions)
myFunction.f1(123).type // "#foo/f1"
myFunction.f2('text').type //"#foo/f2"
myFunction.f3().type // "#foo/f3"
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQQWTYCAOwBo48DiBhdLaAdWBgAsAFdMDdAE1YwE8ANhAzc4AXzgAzKBBBwA5AAEeAVwAeAKwDOAehgQIggNZMFAWABQV5MW3wQ-AGKqi%20QkW1wAvIitxpAEYALjgACk4hEW5QolUQACM0KABKHwA%20cIR-ALhI4VESHPEUossAqQAmUIiBApi4eyhgIgBzNO9MsOzy3PzosoCSwekAZhqOroRhq3ErKxh%20MDQ4ACU0blVkZIAeHIB5BM04NHVsIm4vddsobh2mltayMIA6N65W7VCMIn4AbQAupNEHk6tFvr8JOkRuw0FJgOoTmc0BcvA82jlMr4erk4H92BAwHAWnBjGh%20BApHBDpoAcEcgEKB4aJgDFBGCxYZweHwoqI9r1cXwoBgQGhsFBtDsafjZGAAdCGbl1jBVFAiAAVJZoaVHWWEhV-BT9UQKAEjXEAAwAJAhYfD1OJdLaCUSAGSNGDNNriS1K9LFeaWWyeeBSVzuYgAcRRyToUB8cAFAXtCKR50unu9TxyGvTKMz12gd3RT3CbxeHy%20cB%20-yBGRrvwDlnSEXQDtCqfUZCkNNCGsmOTCNLQ%20BeZP42jCvaOaQwXhwUBF-B2E8pcA16RSLzU2zCYQwyGQZDQgjQIGB3SVFcPx6Vf1P57pKFo2CZxDCNoQYHbCKdtsfEBfR7GVAKBYpSkQSR5zWDYtl2DUyC7Lcg1OSBYBQOwHGcCNKCIRNwzcPCYyIOM2TCBQAGIpEMBQyEcFwiI8bQUisBjcI8F4pECMJAkqUZt0WZY4F0XQ4AAImowxdG48S2JwpjiC4yoKOwM4FEE7URN0SSaIgGTKjkyx2MUoguNGMJNOE0SJKk-SpFGIyrCAA)

**`Reducer`** - iterates through `Obj` keys and creates appropriate value type from `ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload`. This is one to one representation of what you did in `functionGenerator` since `functionGenerator` iterates through all keys and assigns to each key `createAction` return value.

---

Description of `ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload` generic arguments:

```js
export interface ActionCreatorWithPreparedPayload<
  Args extends unknown[],    // list of arguments
  P,                         // payload object
  T extends string = string, // prefix
  E = never,
  M = never
> extends BaseActionCreator<P, T, M, E> {
  /**
   * Calling this {@link redux#ActionCreator} with `Args` will return
   * an Action with a payload of type `P` and (depending on the `PrepareAction`
   * method used) a `meta`- and `error` property of types `M` and `E` respectively.
   */
  (...args: Args): PayloadAction<P, T, M, E>
}
```

[image]

Comment: wow thanks!!
after i published my dirt fixes i see you code and now i will rewrite my code!

Comment: i try understand by myself but cold not find any solution
for :
type TF1 = ReturnType<typeof myFunction.f1>
WebStorm don't see  f1 , f2 , f3  in myFunction

its do auto complete on type TF12 = typeof myFunction.f1

Comment: @Vasa please provide reproducible example with error

Comment: i try past link to Playground its say its 'Too long by 378 characters'
i take you  Playground and add at the end  `type TF1 = ReturnType<typeof myFunction.f1>`

Comment: its don't give me way past Shortener link :/

Comment: please update your question

Comment: i update my question add screenshots and link to playground from you solution 
thanks!

Comment: @Vasa TS does not support autocomplete in this case. Please be aware that autocomplete is sipported in this case `type TF2 = typeof myFunction.f2`

Comment: import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
createSlice on actions in some magic way do generate functions that autocompleted I thought it was similar , i will try research more thanks anyway you answer help me wary match  !!